# Vector and queue of pointers data exchange: deep and shallow copies

Tags: c++, stl

In my code I have a vector of pointers to objects of `SomeClass` and a (custom comparison) vector-based priority queue that contains pointers to objects of `SomeClass`:

```
std::vector<SomeClass*> my_vector;
std::priority_queue<SomeClass*, vector<SomeClass*>, CustomCompare> my_queue;
```

Initially `my_vector` is empty and `my_queue` is full. Gradually `my_queue` is emptied into `my_vector` like this:

```
my_vector.push_back(my_queue.top());
my_queue.pop();
```

My question is: Will `my_queue.pop()` delete the memory that was allocated to the `SomeClass` object that was pushed back to `my_vector` therefore causing the element of `my_vector` to be a dangling pointer? Or otherwise, does the vector make a deep or a shallow copy of the object pointed to by the pointer returned by `my_queue.top()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No deletions will be made. The only thing being copied/removed/pushed_back are pointers. The objects these point to remain alive, *provided they have been dynamically allocated*. In that case, you will have to do the clean-up yourself.

Depending on the behaviour desired, you may want to use [smart poitners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) to avoid manual memory management, store `SomeClass` objects instead of pointers, or leave things as they are and make sure to make a cleanup at the end. Bear in mind that it can be difficult to guarantee that your program will safely get to the point where the memory is released, which is one reason smart pointers are preferred over raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: By _provided they have been dynamically allocated_ do you mean that this is not true if I pass references to statically allocated objects?

Comment: @OrestisTsinalis I mean that if you pass pointers to objects in automatic storage, then you must make sure these don't go out of scope before your vector and queue do, because then you get dangling pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`my_queue.pop()` will only delete the object stored in the queue; in this case, the pointer itself, not the object pointed by the pointer. So you are fine here.

Mandatory remark: consider using smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Both the queue and the vector only contain pointers. Unless you use smart pointers or shared pointers neither the destructor of the queue nor that of the vector will free the memory.

Answer (score 0):

No. Since they store pointers, they will copy and destroy pointers (which is a no-op). There's no magic involved. If they never store a pointer to the same object simultaneously you may want to make then store `unique_ptr`s if you want them to destroy the objects in the end. Alternatively you can store the actual objects in a third vector (`vector<SomeClass>`), and maintain the vector and queue of pointers separately.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing pointer to SomeClass object everywhere, so no my_queue.pop() just removes the pointer from queue and your object is ok, and you will store a copy of pointer to vector, not a deep copy.